# How to reverse a specific word in C?

Tags: c, string

I'm new-ish to C and I am given a task to reverse words in a string.

Example

> input: Hello this is awesome

> Output: awesome is this Hello.

But I only want to modify and put the last word into the first so it would be like:

> awesome Hello this is

how would i go about this problem? Because reversing seems okay, I just have to reverse the whole sentence and reverse each word again, but I only want to do it to a specific word.

Comment: How do you store the string(s)? There are multiple ways to do what you want.

Comment: Look for the first space. If it exists, print everything that follows it, followed by a space. Then print everything from the start of the string up to the first space (or to the end of the string if there is no space). If you need help with any specific part of this, please show the code you've come up with so far and explain what's causing difficulties.

Comment: to operate on a specific word, you first need to define what identify this specific word. Is it the word itself, its initial position ? what is the rule to follow ?

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.